# Set default Docker container domain name

Tags: docker, dns

Is there a way to automatically set containers domain name to be the same as the host one (`hostname -d` to be equal on container and host)?

I can do this manually by setting the `domainname` in the `docker-compose.yml`, but I would like this to be done automatically.

Comment: you mean container name and hostname ?

Comment: Yes and no, I mean the container domain name, which is given by `hostname -d` and is set in `/etc/hosts` on debian like systems, but the domain name is part of the full hostname given by `hostname -f`